# How to upload any type of file in phonegap and jquery mobile ?

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, file-upload, cordova

I am creating an app in the phonegap android in which i want to upload a file to the server. What i want is when an user will click on the upload button an option dialog will open from where the user will select a file to be uploaded and then when user click on the save button the file will be uploaded. The dialog will be like normal window same as we see when we click on the attach button in the mail in the desktop.
Can anyone tell me how to do this in android mobile? 
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use phonegap file transfer method 
The FileTransfer object allows you to upload or download files to and from a server.

**Properties**

1. onprogress: Called with a ProgressEvent whenever a new chunk of data is transferred. (Function)

**Methods**

- upload: sends a file to a server.
- download: downloads a file from server.
- abort: Aborts an in-progress transfer.

**Sample** 
// !! Assumes variable fileURI contains a valid URI to a text file on the device

```
var win = function (r) {
    console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
    console.log("Response = " + r.response);
    console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
}

var fail = function (error) {
    alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
    console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
    console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
}

var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey = "file";
options.fileName = fileURI.substr(fileURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
options.mimeType = "text/plain";

var params = {};
params.value1 = "test";
params.value2 = "param";

options.params = params;

var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(fileURI, encodeURI("http://some.server.com/upload.php"), win, fail, options);
```

**You can browse and select a file using**

```
var source =  navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY;
navigator.camera.getPicture(successFn, errorFn, { quality: 50,
        destinationType: this.photoDestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: source,
        mediaType: navigator.camera.MediaType.ALLMEDIA  });
```

more information Check [link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer)

Comment: what should i do if want to upload file like .pdf,.png,.jpg,.txt bcz it will depend on the user that what kind of file he/she want to upload so what i want is it will open an sdcard and then the user will select what user want to upload.

Comment: in fileURI how to set the path of the directory to chose a file and if we use navigator.camera then the user will only be able to select the image files or they will be able to select any extension file to upload sorry to ask you such question I am new to this.I would be nice if u can give a complete example.